# Amperand (&) in CDATA breaking XML POST Request

Tags: xml, cdata

I am sending an xml request with a '&'  in CDATA

```
<![CDATA[red & blue]]>
```

Its breaking my XML by ending where the `&` is. Any ideas how to avoid this? I have tried `&amp;` also and it still breaks at the same location.

Here is link to request and output of results using curl

http://pastebin.com/8Nh3d5Ty

The Server is running codeigniter

Comment: Please post the XML. What you are describing shouldn't be happening as text in CDATA sections does not need to be escaped.

Comment: Also tell us what it is that "still breaks".  What software are you using and what errors are you encountering.  PLEASE read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.  If you don't follow those suggestions your questions will get closed.

Comment: Here is my request and output http://pastebin.com/8Nh3d5Ty. I am using curl to make my requests and the server is running on codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "breaking"? You need to be more specific about what you are doing and what is going wrong.

If you are using a SAX parser, note that SAX can break text nodes up into pieces and deliver the pieces one at a time. It can break the nodes anywhere, but it's not uncommon for SAX parsers to break them at characters that are significant to the parser, such as '&'.

I've now looked at your pastebin message (hard to read yellow on white...). I'm not familiar with the tools you are using but they seem badly broken. It's actually not recognizing the CDATA section, it's serializing it as `"&lt;![CDATA["` which is clearly wrong. If it's not recognizing the CDATA then it's probably going to treat the ampersand as starting an entity reference, so after that, all bets are off.

Comment: Hi Michael, The tool I am using is curl to send requests. I have figured out the problem as http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2001-08/0139.html curl does that "&lt;![CDATA[" changing < to '&lt;'. This is a curl issue not handling special characters in the data string. Thanks for your time and responses everyone.